# How to select first 280 words of text up to the closest period?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to extract a shorter segment of text of a specified number of words from a longer one. I can do this using

```
text = "There was a very big cat that was sitting on the ledge. It was  overlooking the garden. The dog next door watched with curiosity."

    text.split[0..15].join(' ')
    >>""There was a very big cat that was sitting on the ledge. It was  overlooking"
```

I would like to select the text up to the next period so I don't end up with a partial sentence.

Is there a way possibly using a Regex to accomplish what I'm trying to do that will be able to get the text  up to and including the closest next period after the 15th word?

Comment: May be [another alternative](https://regex101.com/r/nn6lfn/2)

Comment: You may wish to sharpen your statement of the question. My understanding is that you wish to obtain a substring of `text` that begins at the beginning of `text`, ends with a punctuation character and contains as few words as possible, but not less than 15 words. Also, the title should be changed to remove the reference to `"280"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\w+[,.?!]?\s+){14}(?:\w+,?\s+)*?\w+[.?!]
```

Repeats a word, optional [comma/period/question mark/exclamation mark], and spaces, 14 times. Then, it lazy-repeats a word followed by a space, followed by another word and a period, ensuring that the pattern ends at the first period after 15 words from the start.

https://regex101.com/r/ardIQ7/4

Comment: Thank you. Works very well. What if I wanted to add any sentence ending punctuation such as ? and ! Would it be ?:\w+\.\?\!?\s+){15}(?:\w+\s?)*?\.\!\?

Comment: Use a character set instead of the `\.` (which only matches a literal period)

Comment: (?:\w+[\.!?]?\s+){15}(?:\w+\s?)*?[\.!?] seems to work.

Comment: Looks good, though you don't need to escape periods inside a character set - there, they match the literal period by default.

Comment: I think I need some adjustments. When I use a large text, it seems to select groups of 15 text, some of which is within the body of the text and not at the start. I just want to have the first match of 15 words starting from the beginning of the text.

Comment: Make sure not to use the global flag - that will return *all* matches, rather than just the first match. (like in the regex101 - see how there's no `/g`)

Comment: Try the one in https://regex101.com/r/ardIQ7/1 with a large amount of text. It selects 15 words in the middle of the text. Any ideas? I really appreciate your help

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem given the text input. It *should* match as soon as it can - it'll only backtrack and move on to the next position if the starting position fails, which I don't *think* should happen with a paragraph-like string with words, spaces, and `[.!?]`. If there are commas, you can probably manage them with `(?:\w+[,.?!]?\s+){15}(?:\w+,?\s+)*?\w+\.`. If that's not it, can you post a link to a regex101 that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Yep, there are commas there. Include a comma in the first character set, and include an optional comma before the space when you're repeating words *after* the 15th word - see edit

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    (?:           # begin a non-capture group
      \p{Alpha}+  # match one or more letters
      [.!?]?      # optionally ('?' following ']') match one of the 3 punctuation chars
      [ ]+        # match one or more spaces
    )             # end non-capture group
    {14,}?        # execute the preceding non-capture group at least 14 times, lazily ('?')
    \p{Alpha}+    # match one or more letters  
    [.!?]         # match one of the three punctuation characters
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode

text[r]
  #=> "There was a very big cat that was sitting on the ledge. It was overlooking 
  #    the garden.
```

Free-spacing mode strips out spaces, which is why the space character above is in a character class (`[ ]+`). Written conventionally, the regex is as follows.

```
/(?:\p{Alpha}+[.!?]? +){14,}?\p{Alpha}+[.!?]/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```
text = "There was a very big cat that was sitting on the ledge. It was  overlooking the garden. The dog next door watched with curiosity."

tgt=15
old_text=text.scan(/[^.]+\.\s?/)
new_text=[]
while (old_text && new_text.join.scan(/\b\p{Alpha}+\b/).length<=tgt) do
   new_text << old_text.shift
end   

p new_text.join
```

Prints:

```
"There was a very big cat that was sitting on the ledge. It was  overlooking the garden. "
```

That works with any length of normal sentences and will break as soon as 1 additional sentence exceeds the word target.